# How to add comments to folders

Tags: directory

How to add the comments to the folders in Windows XP. When i arrange the folders in details view and right click below the address bar there are list of options in that one option is Comment i want to add the comments to folders and based on that i want to arrange it.

How to achieve this?

Comment: Maybe try on serverfault.com for an answer.

Comment: How does this have anything to do with Servers?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you mean a mouse-over description, then:

1. Right-click the folder and select Properties.
2. From the Properties dialog box, select the Customize tab, and then click the Change Icon button.
3. In the Change Icon dialog box, select an icon from the selections and click OK.
4. Click OK to close the Properties dialog box.
5. Open the folder, locate the Desktop.ini file, and double-click it.
6. Add InfoTip= to the end of the Desktop.ini file.
7. Type your detailed description immediately after the = sign.
8. Go to File | Save and close Notepad.

You'll see your detailed pop-up description the next time you mouse over that folder.